# Не видно текста на TableRow

Tags: java, android, textview, android-layout-inflater

Есть такой "шаблон":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/termin_item_bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/terminNumb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/terminKZ"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:text="Қазақша атауы" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/terminRU"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:text="Орысша атауы" />
</TableRow>
```

Добавляю через этот код TableRow, TableRow выводит, но вот TextView'а не видно, т.е. пустой

```
String[] kzTermins = {"Бірінші термин", "Екінші термин", "Үшнші термин" };
String[] ruTermins = {"Первый термин", "Второй термин", "Третий термин" };
final TableLayout termins_result_list = (TableLayout) termins_container.findViewById(R.id.termins_result_list);
terminsTables(0, kzTermins, ruTermins, termins_result_list);

private static LayoutInflater tableRowInflater = LayoutInflater.from(App.getContext());
public static void terminsTables(int terminNumb, String[] kzTermins, String[] ruTermins, final TableLayout termins_result_list) {
    int newNumb = terminNumb;
    int terminsLength =  kzTermins.length;
    TableRow rowTitle;

    for (int i = 0; i < terminsLength; i++) {
        rowTitle = (TableRow) tableRowInflater.inflate(R.layout.termins_table_row, null);

        TextView tNumb = (TextView) rowTitle.findViewById(R.id.terminNumb);
        tNumb.setText(String.valueOf(i+1));

        TextView tKZ = (TextView) rowTitle.findViewById(R.id.terminKZ);
        tKZ.setText(kzTermins[i]);

        TextView tRU = (TextView) rowTitle.findViewById(R.id.terminRU);
        tRU.setText(ruTermins[i]);

        termins_result_list.addView(rowTitle);
    }

}
```

Comment: у вас не одно текствью а несколько какой из них не видно?

Comment: не видно ни одного

Answer (score 2):

Нашел решение. Оказывается если не указать цвет текста, то по умолчание цвет будет белым. Поэтому надо явно указать цвет текста либо в разметке либо в коду, но лучше в разметке.

Answer (score 0):

У вас какая-то путаница в разметке.

1. Не факт, что можно прямо несколько вьюх в `TableRow` положить, не оборачивая в контейнер типа `LinearLayout` - иначе не ясно как они должны внутри отображаться.
2. `android:width` и `android:height` - таких атрибутов нет в андроиде. Только         `android:layout_width` `android:layout_height` - используйте только их.
3. У вас у всех вьюх размеры во весь контейнер - по идее будет виден только один из них. Наверное вам надо `wrap_content` вместо `match_parent`
4. Как вы хотите вес и `gravity` использовать - не ясно.

Comment: дело не в разметке, это 100%, т.к. этот кусок с рабочей разметки